Difference between Echelon TPT/XF and RS485 transceivers
We are going to connect to a LonWorks network and all devices connected to network have TP/XF-78 transceiver. Can anyone describe the difference between the two?

What did Echelon say?

@MrGerber In a document, they say TP/XF-78 is transformer-coupled bus topology. They also have TP-RS485-39 transceiver which is compatible with EIA RS-485 spec.
